# Return a value before executing a function similar to setstate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a function that returns a value that I can check against before executing something if i need to. Similar to reacts setState.  So something like:

```
changeState(initialState => {
  console.log(initialState);
  return 'Hello';
});
```

but can also be used simply like:

```
changeState('hello');
```

How is this handled? It seems like it should be simple but I for some reason can't get a grasp on how to pull this off.  Does anyone know how react handles this situation.

Comment: not clear what you want, explain more

Comment: are you trying to make a hook that sets state but also returns the new value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what you are wanting to accomplish but checking the `typeof` the arguments is probably what you are looking for.

Simple example that assigns an object property value based on function or primitive as first argument

```js
const state = {
  foo: 1
}

const changeFoo = (...args) => {
  if (typeof args[0] === 'function') {
    // assign value as result of function passing in initial value
    state.foo = args[0](state.foo)
  } else {
    // assign value directly
    state.foo = args[0]
  }
};

// set value directly
changeFoo(2)
console.log('after set 2:', state.foo)// expect 2
// set value as return of function
changeFoo((initial) => initial + 1)
console.log('after func:', state.foo)// expect 3
```